# Why some apps don't respond to app zoom shortcut?

Tags: macos

I added "zoom" app shortcut to keyboard preferences, to maximize app windows. It works on most apps, but some (third party) don't react. I can still maximize them dragging the edges with the mouse. Any idea why?

Comment: Apps that don’t behave like apps generally are cross platform and lack any sort of hook. Can you name any of these apps so we can confirm?

Comment: @bmike the emacs app.

Comment: The emacs program Apple ships runs in the terminal app which respects zoom for me. Perhaps you have a specific one you’re using?

Comment: @bmike It's the gui app. Installed with e.g. `brew cask install emacs`.

Comment: @bmike this is the source http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/, seems written in c, no idea which framework.